# Why is it that as an object moves away from a light source, its light waves will expand and the frequency of the wave will change?

Tags: redshift

As measured in blueshift and redshift, if you were to move closer to an object, its light waves would compress and become "bluer". If you were to move away from an object, the opposite happens. Why is it that the distance between the photons in the wave changes?

Comment: It's not the *distance* that causes the phenomenon,  it's the *relative speed* of the observer and source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no evidence of prior effort.

Comment: I did research this, I just couldn't find a proper answer.

Answer (score 3):

First the wavelength or frequency of light has nothing to do with the distance between photons. A single photon has a frequency which is directly proportional to the energy it carries. Second, the red shift or blue shift you are referring to is called Doppler effect and I suggest you have a look on Wikipedia which has an excellent article on the subject: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect

This effect is unrelated to the photon nature of light – you can just consider light as a wave to understand this.

Comment: What. I mean is why do the wavelengths of the photons change as you move further or closer?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something, but Doppler effect is not about the distance from the object but about the relative speed. Is it what the question is about? If it is about explaining how Doppler effect works, I suggest you try to read the Wikipedia page. If you have more specific questions I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Actually, I have read part of the Wikipedia page, but it is kind of confusing

Answer (score 0):

Everything is relative.

From the point of view of the emitter, it's frequency may be fixed and stable.

From the point of view of an observer, who is moving in relation to the emitter, this may not be true. If the observer is moving toward / away from the emitter at a suitable speed, the observed frequency of the emitter is going to change.

You can experience this with cars passing on the road... it's especially noticeable with horns. As the car passes there is a noticeable shift in pitch, from higher to lower as the car changes from coming towards, to going away.
If you were sitting in the car (or traveling beside it at a more similar speed), the horn would sound like it is at a constant pitch.

This phenomenon is called the [Doppler Effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect).